# WPF ScrollView and TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollview, textblock

What am I doing wrong?

The following code works:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollChatMessages">
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtChatMessages" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

But once I touch it up with the designer so it looks neater and doesn't take over the entire Grid, the ScrollView doesn't scroll the content of the Scrollblock anymore:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollChatMessages" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="181" Margin="95,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtChatMessages" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="181" Width="300"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Could someone explain this behaviour to me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i dont get your issue

Comment: @Sajeetharan In the first code, the ScrollView is able to scroll so everything that falls out of view from TextBlock can get seen by scrolling. With the second code, everything is placed where I want it, but the scrollbar doesnt correspond to the TextBlock anymore all of the sudden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to say for sure. But you can see that the Designer has added a bunch of new property values for both elements. In particular, the `ScrollViewer` and `TextBlock` have been set to have the same exact width and height.

Naturally, with the contained element having exactly the correct dimensions to fit within the `ScrollViewer`, there's no need to scroll to see all of it. You need to remove the `Width` and `Height` property values from the `TextBlock`.

Comment: Now I have a better understanding of why my solution worked! Thank you very much! Even though my solution works, your answer gives me knowledge on a more broad scale so I will mark your solution as answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by placing it inside of a Grid.

```
<Grid x:Name="gridChatMessages" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="181" Margin="95,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollChatMessages">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtChatMessages" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```